# Magento - Onclick View.php Methods?

Tags: php, magento, methods, module, call

I’ve gotten fairly familiar with Magento’s design structure and now taking my hand out developing for it.

Anyway, what i’m trying to do is add a few buttons to the Sales/Order menu which gives the option to click a button which then sends out a predefined template (for example returns/despatched product).

I have the email method sorted due to some fairly meaty Google’ing but trying to call this method within the view.php is proviing to be a hassle. I can get the method to run, but it will run without the button being clicked and is very evident with the ‘Works!!’ stuck at the top and messing with Magento’s styling.

I have been looking at the onclick method of doing this:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('MyTux_Email_Model_Email');
if($this->_isAllowedAction('Despatch'))
{
    $this->_addButton('Despatched', array(
    $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure this item has been despatched?'),
    'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Despatch Confirm'),
    'onclick' => $model->_sendStatusMail($order),
    ));
 }
```

I’ve tried every which way of modifying this, i’ve used a variety of booleans mixed with if statements i.e. if button is click then do this else do bugger all, but nothing seems to properly encapsulate the method.

The custom module has been setup correctly, the real hurdle i now have to figure out is calling the method. As you can see i’ve made it a global helper so I can get at the method easily. But really proving to be troublesome, has anyone have any ideas how I can go about accomplishing of:

onclick - call the method! Just not call it when the page loads! :|

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve managed to get it working (really buggy at the moment) with a push in the right direction over at StackOverflow. I\’m going to detail what I had to do in order for this to work for others use:

1. Create an Index Controller in your custom module. Magento Wiki has an tutorial on this.
2. Setup your config.xml with the following (this is frontend, this module is meant to be backend, so just for the sake of an example) with the following:

   ```
   ...
   <frontend>
   <routers>
       <namespace_module>
           <use>standard</use>
           <args>
               <module>namespace_module</module>
               <frontName>modulename</frontName>
           </args>
       </namespace_module>
   </routers>  
   </frontend>
   ...
   ```

The front name would refer to: http://yoursite.com/modulename, change as you see fit.

3:  Use the following as a base example for your method:

```
    'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation(\'{$message}','{$this->getUrl('namespace_module')}\')",
```

4: To acquire your orderId and Order use the following:

```
    class MyTux_Email_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {        
        public function indexAction() 
        {
          $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam(\'order_id\');
           $order = Mage::getModel(\'sales/order\')->load($orderId);
            $model = Mage::getModel(\'Your_Custom_Model_Name\');
             $email = $model->_sendStatusMail($order);
        }
    }
```

5: Followed by any relevant Model calls of yours. Make sure to call the order at the controller level however. Nightmare to figure out this, but hopefully this post will help someone out who has a similar dilemma!

Answer (score 1):

The onclick option sets the onclick attribute of the HTML button tag. It doesn't get executed by Magento.

The way I've seen this done is to create a controller and route to handle the request and set onclick to redirect the browser to the URL for the controller or make an AJAX call to the controller.

Comment: Thanks bud, real nice push in the right direction I had no idea where to even start!

Comment: Thanks weirdo i've managed to come to a solution, tried to self answer but won't let me for another 8 hours!

Comment: Glad to help. Can't wait to see what you came up with!